# Get a series of lower case letters sorted

Tags: c, arrays, string, quicksort

The algorithm works fine with integers but since I converted them into char, it has been printing null for the output:

```
/* sort a series of lower case letters using quicksort algorithm. */ 
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

// since c gets the ascii code when returning an int for a char variable.

char quicksort(char a[], char low, char high);
char split(char a[], char low, char high);
int a[N];

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    printf("Enter  letters to be sorted: ");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    quicksort(a, 0, N - 1);

    printf("In sorted order: ");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%s ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
char quicksort(char a[], char low, char high)
{
    int middle;

    if (low >= high) return;
    middle = split(a, low, high);
    quicksort(a, low, middle - 1);
    quicksort(a, middle + 1, high);
}
char split(char a[], char low, char high)
{
    char part_element = a[low];

    for (;;) {
        while (low < high && part_element <= a[high])
            high--;
        if (low >= high) break;
        a[low++] = a[high];

        while (low < high && a[low] <= part_element)
            low++;
        if (low >= high) break;
        a[high--] = a[low];
    }

    a[high] = part_element;
    return high;
}
```

Comment: In `scanf` use "%c" to read a char.

Comment: Unless you just want to play with the quicksort algorithm, you are much better off using `qsort` from `stdlib.h`. All you do is write a comparison function and then call `qsort` passing the array, size, element size, and the comparison function. 5-lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The revised code still doesnt work and i cant seem to find the bug.

Your problems appear to be with `main()` pretty much along the lines that other folks have suggested with respect to using `char` oriented data instead of `int`.  There are some non fatal questionable choice issues like using `char` datatypes for array indexes; `quicksort()` is declared to return `char` but returns nothing; and so forth.  Below is a rework of your code, mostly for style, incorporating various folks suggestions:

```
/* sort a series of letters using quicksort algorithm. */ 

#include <stdio.h>

#define N (10)

void quicksort(char a[], int low, int high);
int split(char a[], int low, int high);

int main(void)
{
    char a[N];

    printf("Enter letters to be sorted: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%c", &a[i]);
    }

    quicksort(a, 0, N - 1);

    printf("In sorted order: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%c ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void quicksort(char a[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high) {
        int middle = split(a, low, high);
        quicksort(a, low, middle - 1);
        quicksort(a, middle + 1, high);
    }
}

int split(char a[], int low, int high)
{
    char part_element = a[low];

    for (;;) {
        while (low < high && part_element <= a[high]) {
            high--;
        }
        if (low >= high) {
            break;
        }
        a[low++] = a[high];

        while (low < high && a[low] <= part_element) {
            low++;
        }
        if (low >= high) {
            break;
        }
        a[high--] = a[low];
    }

    a[high] = part_element;

    return high;
}
```

Does it not do everything it's supposed to?

**EXAMPLE**

```
> ./a.out
Enter letters to be sorted: aadircslne
In sorted order: a a c d e i l n r s 
>
```

Comment: looks like there is a problem in the split function since it doesnt show all the letters in the output.

Comment: @arihanian -- provide an example of input/output where it fails.   I've added a usage example to my answer -- are you adding spaces or some such to your input?

Comment: that was bad on my part. the program runs perfectly. this really helps a lot since i am speedrunning the basics of c and i was stuckon the quicksort algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Three issues:

1. `a` is declared as an array of `int`, but all your functions handle an array of `char`.  This means they won't iterate through the array correctly.  Change it to `char a[N]`.
2. To read a character, use the `%c` format specifier to `scanf`.
3. To print a character, use the `%c` format specifier to `printf`.

Comment: why don't just debug it?

Answer (score 0):

[`scanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) requires a `%c` format specifier. Your `scanf` should change to

```
scanf("%c", &a[i]);
```

As a result, you should redeclare the `a` array to `char`, not `int`.